# How to convert datatype.date format to MMYYYY

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I change  `[DisplayFormat]` of date from `DD/MM/YYYY` to `MM/YYYY` inside the model class? 
I tried already:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat( DataFormatString = "MM yyyy")]
```

so it will show for example 08/2018

Comment: How are you displaying your value in the view? Are you using `Html.DisplayFor()`?

Comment: no
    @Html.EditorFor(.......)

Comment: i'm sorry but none of the following didnt work for me...

Answer (score 1):

Apply DataAnnotation like:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/yyyy}")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/yyyy}")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply DataAnnotation in Model like this:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMM/yyyy}")]
```

Comment: Can you tell me what you want exactly date format ?

Comment: i want to show exp date of credit card - i dont care if it will shows as 
08\2019
or aug 2019

Comment: look here http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/23/date-formatting-in-c

Comment: thanks but it not supposed to be in view but in model, 
nice and helpful link but this is not what i trying to do.

Comment: you can get Aug 2019 date format in c#. Are you try this in c#

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for the View :

```
@model.RegisteredDate.ToString("dd MMMM , yyyy")
```

This will give `21 August , 2016` of Format.
If you refer `21 Aug , 2016` then just use "MMM"

Or if in model class

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
```

Comment: this is not what i'm trying to do :-) 
thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TextBoxFor` overload that accepts a formatting parameter like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateMember, "{0: MM yyyy}")
```

If you need to, you can add HTML attributes also (for instance to use a datepicker)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateMember, "{0: MM yyyy}", new { @id="datepicker" })
```